# How can I use automated integration tests across multiple frameworks (internet browsers) without duplicating effort?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, xunit

To give more detail, we have a series of tests we want duplicated across three frameworks (using Selenium for UI stimulation): IE, Mozilla, and Chrome.  The first solution was to duplicate the tests in separate test classes, i.e. each test class had the same 20 test cases with a different framework in the constructor.  The second solution was to use parameterized inputs (or an XUnit theory) with each framework type as an input:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The non-default constructor that initializes
    /// necessary instances of objects that are being used
    /// </summary>
    public VerifyViewUsingChrome() {
        _testBases = new Dictionary<FunctionalTestBase.DriverType, TestBase>();
        _testBases.Add(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.Chrome, new TestBase(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.Chrome));
        _testBases.Add(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.IE, new TestBase(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.IE));
        _testBases.Add(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.FireFox, new TestBase(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.FireFox));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Our simple country display test.
    /// </summary>
    [InlineData(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.Chrome)]
    [InlineData(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.FireFox)]
    [InlineData(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.IE)]
    [Theory]
    public void TestADisplayedForACountry(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType testBase) {
        _testBases[testBase].TestADisplayedForACountry();
    }
```

The issue with this implementation is that all 3 implementations have to be running for each test, which requires some overhead.  Ideally, we would run all the IE tests, then build the Firefox framework and run those tests before continuing on with Chrome.

It may not be possible using a test framework, but for we have convenient tie-ins with our build server, so keeping the test format would be ideal.

Comment: Are you using Selenium?

Comment: Yes.  That is how we are stimulating the UI.

Comment: Perhaps that should have been mentioned in the question or tags. But no sweat now - you've found the solution that suits you.

Comment: Got it - I went ahead and updated the text and tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the solution was simpler than I thought.  The constructor gets called before every test, so the framework startup and tear-will happen regardless of how the tests are run (which makes sense, since you don't want any bleed through from previous tests).

Here is what we decide to do:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The non-default constructor that initializes
    /// necessary instances of objects that are being used
    /// </summary>
    public VerifyViewUsing() { }


    /// <summary>
    /// Our simple country display test.
    /// </summary>
    [InlineData(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.Chrome)]
    [InlineData(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.FireFox)]
    [InlineData(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.IE)]
    [Theory]
    public void TestADisplayedForACountry(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType testBaseType) {
        TestBase testBase = new TestBase(testBaseType);
        testBase.TestADisplayedForACountry();
    }
```

This functions pretty much exactly how we wanted it to.  Each test is independent, duplicated across frameworks, and run with the results linked to the framework used.

Edit:  An actual better method would be this:

```
   public static IEnumerable<object[]> DriverTypes {
        get {
            // Or this could read from a file. :)
            return new[]
            {
                new object[] {  FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.Chrome },
                new object[] {  FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.IE},
                new object[] {  FunctionalTestBase.DriverType.FireFox}
            };
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies that Brucellosis is displayed in the Disease List for
    /// Zimbabwe
    /// </summary>
    [Theory, MemberData("DriverTypes")]
    public void TestClickingADiseaseLinkDisplaysACreatePage(FunctionalTestBase.DriverType testBaseType) {
        TestBase testBase = new TestBase(testBaseType);
        testBase.TestClickingADiseaseLinkDisplaysACreatePage();
    }
```

This allows you to define your frameworks one time, and use them across the project.